# Custom 404 page not being displayed in Apache + PHP-FPM

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, fpm

Context: Apache + PHP-FPM. Migrated a website to a new server. 404s stopped working. Instead of redirecting to a custom page, 404 errors now show the text "File not found."

Expectations: https://nobleme.com/404

Reality: https://nobleme.com/notapage

My .htaccess used to work on my previous server with the following directive (which I haven't touched):

```
RewriteEngine On
ErrorDocument 404 https://nobleme.com/404
```

I have tried including the following directive both in my httpd.conf and my website.conf, but to no avail:

```
ProxyErrorOverride On
```

The only notable difference between my previous server and the current one is usage of PHP-FPM, so it might be a related issue. Any pointers on how to solve this would be much appreciated.

Comment: Probably useful extra info: When people reach the (wrong) 404 message, I get this in error_log: `[proxy_fcgi:error] AH01071: Got error 'Primary script unknown'`

Comment: More info from running apache in debug mode, the AH01071 is followed by a `AH00943: FCGI: has released connection for (*)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved it myself.

`ProxyErrorOverride` is a terrible idea, don't do that.

Instead edit your `/etc/httpd/conf.d/php.conf`

Look for `SetHandler`

And add a condition that the file must exist before the handling happens

Then reboot your apache to update the configuration

Here's an example of that section of my php.conf:

```
  <FilesMatch \.(php|phar)$>
    <If "-f %{REQUEST_FILENAME}">
      SetHandler "proxy:unix:/run/php-fpm/www.sock|fcgi://localhost"
    </If>
  </FilesMatch>
```

Hope this helps someone in the future.

Comment: Your question is incomplete and details on the virtualhost and the application are required. This answer will break some sites for 404s (WordPress, Laravel, etc). The best answer requires details in the question so that others can make an informed choice.